# Why are c++11 random distributions mutable?

Tags: c++, random, c++11

I thought that the value generated by the c++11 random distribution (`uniform_int_distribution`, for instance), depends only on the state of the generator which is passed to the `operator()`. However, for some reason there is no `const` specifier in the signature of `operator()`. What does that mean, and how should I pass the distribution as a function parameter? I thought I had to pass it as any non-mutable parameter: by const reference, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: Operators () in distributions are non-const by standard... So, use reference instead of const-reference.

Comment: Yeah, I understand this is defined in the c++ standard, I don't understand the reason for this. For example, the uniform int distribution can be fully parametrized by its left and right bounds, the normal distribution by the mean and the standard deviation, the discrete distribution by the individual probabilities, etc. So it can be done at the moment of construction, and it seems there is no reason to allow changing the distribution instance (especially for `operator()`).

Comment: I don't know about work of operator () for any distribution, but may be one of them change self state in this function? Distribution is interface and it should satisfies reqs in table 118 (25.1.6/3)

Comment: Distributions are (conceptually) stateful functions (in practice some may be implemented in a stateless manner).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I would argue that. The distribution is a mathematical concept, and the value which will be generated by the distribution next does not depend on the value which was generated in the previous moment. If someone has to keep some hidden state to avoid some computation or for another reason, he should use mutable specifier to the fields, but logically, distribution has to be immutable.

Comment: Suppose it were `const`. Then suppose you passed it to a number of functions in a row utilizing `operator()` - they would (likely, due to implementation) all then generate the same numbers because no state had been changed. That's bad.

Comment: @karlicoss that may be true for true random number generators, but it is absolutely not how just about every single PRNG works.

Comment: @Yuushi nope, the state is changed and it is the hidden state of the generator we pass to the `operator()`

Comment: @karlicoss I thought you were using C++, not doing mathematics. In C++ distributions are stateful functions.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes yeah, I use c++, but when we use some mathematical concepts in programming languages, we try to write code so that is will correspond to the theory if it does not result in some overcomplications, right? So I understand in c++ they *are* stateful, I don't understand *why* they are.

Comment: @karlicoss Sorry, I misunderstood you. I've posted something of an answer now that I understand what you were asking (good question by the way), but I certainly can't give a definitive answer. Hopefully someone with more inside knowledge may be able to shine more light on this.

Comment: All the state of the random generator should be in the engine, not the distribution. I don't think that it makes sense for `operator()` to not have a const qualifier.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I misunderstood the question at first, however, now that I understand, it's a good question. Some digging into the source of the implementation of `<random>` for g++ gives the following (with a few bits left out for clarity):

```
template<typename _IntType = int>
  class uniform_int_distribution
  {

  struct param_type
  {
    typedef uniform_int_distribution<_IntType> distribution_type;

    explicit
    param_type(_IntType __a = 0,
       _IntType __b = std::numeric_limits<_IntType>::max())
    : _M_a(__a), _M_b(__b)
    {
      _GLIBCXX_DEBUG_ASSERT(_M_a <= _M_b);
    }

     private:
    _IntType _M_a;
    _IntType _M_b;
};

public:
  /**
   * @brief Constructs a uniform distribution object.
   */
  explicit
  uniform_int_distribution(_IntType __a = 0,
           _IntType __b = std::numeric_limits<_IntType>::max())
  : _M_param(__a, __b)
  { }

  explicit
  uniform_int_distribution(const param_type& __p)
  : _M_param(__p)
  { }

  template<typename _UniformRandomNumberGenerator>
result_type
operator()(_UniformRandomNumberGenerator& __urng)
    { return this->operator()(__urng, this->param()); }

  template<typename _UniformRandomNumberGenerator>
result_type
operator()(_UniformRandomNumberGenerator& __urng,
       const param_type& __p);

  param_type _M_param;
};
```

If we squint past all the `_`, we can see that it has only a single member parameter, `param_type _M_param`, which itself is simply a nested struct holding 2 integral values - in effect, a range. `operator()` is only declared here, not defined. Some more digging brings us to the definition. In lieu of posting all the code here, which is pretty ugly (and rather long), it suffices to say that nothing is mutated inside this function. In fact, adding `const` to definition and declaration will happily compile.

The question then becomes, is this true for every other distribution? The answer is no. If we look to the implementation for `std::normal_distribution`, we find:

```
template<typename _RealType>
template<typename _UniformRandomNumberGenerator>
  typename normal_distribution<_RealType>::result_type
  normal_distribution<_RealType>::
  operator()(_UniformRandomNumberGenerator& __urng,
     const param_type& __param)
  {
result_type __ret;
__detail::_Adaptor<_UniformRandomNumberGenerator, result_type>
  __aurng(__urng);

    //Mutation!
if (_M_saved_available)
  {
    _M_saved_available = false;
    __ret = _M_saved;
  }
    //Mutation!
```

This is all just theorizing, but I imagine the reason it is not restricted to `const` is to allow implementers to mutate their implementation if required. Further, it keeps a more uniform interface - if some `operator()` are `const` and some are non-`const`, it all becomes a bit messy.

<s>However, why they didn't simply make them const and let the implementers utilize `mutable` I'm not sure. Likely, unless someone around here was involved with this part of the standardization effort, you may not get a good answer to this.</s>

Edit: As MattieuM pointed out, `mutable` and multiple threads do not play nicely together.

Just as a minorly interesting aside, `std::normal_distribution` generates two values at once, caching one (hence the `_M_saved`). The `operator<<` that it defines actually lets you see this value before the next call to `operator()`:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

std::default_random_engine eng(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
std::normal_distribution<> d(0, 1);

int main()
{
   auto k = d(eng);
   std::cout << k << "\n";
   std::cout << d << "\n";
   std::cout << d(eng) << "\n";
}
```

Here, the output format is `mu sigma nextval`.

Comment: There is no reason to make them const and use mutable because the distributions are not logically const: if they were you could just make a new distribution each time you need a new number; as is you cannot because, for those that have mutation, it gives you a badly distributed sequence. If you want a properly distributed sequence you *must* use the same distribution object to generate all numbers in that sequence and the non-const interface reflects that.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes For something like `std::uniform_int_distribution` you *could* have it make a new distribution each time, and it would be perfectly fine, even as implemented. Drawing numbers from a distribution should (theoretically) not modify the distribution itself in any way. If I draw a number from a normal distribution with mu=0 and sigma=1, the distribution remains a normal distribution with mu=0 and sigma=1 after that.

Comment: Despite sharing the same name, distributions in C++ are not the same entity as distributions from mathematics. That is something you just have to accept. The truth is that some C++ distributions have mutable state *and that state is observable* (it may not be *easy* to observe it because we are talking about randomness and probabilities, though): writing code that assumes there is no observable state leads to badly distributed output. And `mutable` should never be used to hide observable state.

Comment: @Yuushi: The Standard refuses to hide mutability because it aims to guarantee that `const` operations on an object may be safely invoked from multiple threads. This is why, for example, COW is now forbidden by the C++11 Standard.

Comment: @MatthieuM. is every const-method invocation on an object guaranteed to be thread-safe? So that mean if we use a mutable field, we have to guarantee thread safety (use a mutex) when doing writes to it in a const-specified method?

Comment: @karlicoss: I am not sure about *every* single access across the entire library, but I do know it is a design goal and it has been enforced for all STL containers and the `basic_string` class.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes "Despite sharing the same name, distributions in C++ are not the same entity as distributions from mathematics. That is something you just have to accept" the OP is asking why it is so, so that doesn't really answer the question (and this answer seems to argue it is an implementation detail, that is a bit weak).

Answer (score 1):

The other answer says:

> This is all just theorizing, but I imagine the reason it is not restricted to const is to allow implementers to mutate their implementation if required. Further, it keeps a more uniform interface - if some operator() are const and some are non-const, it all becomes a bit messy.

This is mostly correct, but it is even deeper than that in the context of generic programming. 
(As @Calimo said, this leaves the idea that `const` was omitted just "in case").

After thinking about this, I reached the conclusion that the problem translates on whether the following member function can be *in principle* `const` or not really depends on the actual type of `_UniformRandomNumberGenerator`.

```
template<typename _UniformRandomNumberGenerator>
result_type
operator()(_UniformRandomNumberGenerator& __urng)
```

At this level of (generic) specification this is not know, so it is only then that "[the specification] allows implementers to mutate [internal state] " and it does it for the sake of genericity.

So, the problem of constness is that *at compile-time* one should know whether  `_UniformRandomNumberGenerator` is able to generate enough randomness (bits) for the distribution to produce a sample draw.

In the current specification that possibility is left out but it can in principle be implemented (or specified) by having two exclusive versions of the member function:

```
template<typename _URG, typename = std::enable_if<not has_enough_randomness_for<_URG, result_type>::value > >
result_type
operator()(_UniformRandomNumberGenerator& __urng){..statefull impl..}

template<typename _URG, typename = std::enable_if<has_enough_randomness_for<_URG, result_type>::value > >
result_type
operator()(_UniformRandomNumberGenerator& __urng) const{..stateless impl...}
```

Where `has_enough_randomness_for` is an imagined boolean metafunction that can tell if the particular implementation can be stateless.

However, there is still another obstacle, in general, whether the implementation is stateless or not depends on the *runtime parameters* of the distribution. 
But since this is runtime information then it cannot be passed as part of the type system!

As you see this opens another can of worms. `constexpr` parameters of the distributions could in principle detect this but I would totally understand the committee stopping here.

If you need an immutable distribution (e.g. to be "conceptually" correct) you could achieve this easily by paying a price:

1. Copying a pristine distribution each time before using it.
2. Implementing the distribution logic yourself in a stateless manner.

(1) can be very inefficient and (2) it is likely to be somewhat inefficient and *extremely* tricky to implement correctly.

Since (2) is almost impossible to get right in general and even if one gets it right, it will be somewhat inefficient, I am only going to show how to implement a stateless distribution that just works:

```
template<class Distribution>
struct immutable : Distribution{
   using Distribution::Distribution;
   using Distribution::result_type;
   template<typename _URG> result_type operator()(_URG& __urng) const{
      auto dist_copy = static_cast<Distribution>(*this);
      return dist_copy(__urng);
   }
// template<typename _URG> result_type operator()(_URG& __urng) = delete;
};
```

In such a way that `immutable<D>` is a replacement for `D`.  (Another name for `immutable<D>` could be `conceptual<D>`.)

I have tested this with `uniform_real_distribution` for example and the `immutable` replacement is almost twice as slow (because it copies/modifies/discards a nominal state), but as you point out it can be used in a more "conceptual" context if that is important to your design (which I can understand).

(There is another minor unrelated advantage that is that you can use a shared immutable distribution across threads)

---

**INCORRECT BUT ILLUSTRATIVE CODE FOLLOWS:**

To illustrate how difficult is to do (2), I am going to make a *naive* specialization of `immutable<std::uniform_int_distribution>` that is almost correct for some uses (or very incorrect depending on who you ask.)

```
template<class Int>
struct immutable<std::uniform_int_distribution<Int>> : std::uniform_int_distribution<Int>{
   using std::uniform_int_distribution<Int>::uniform_int_distribution;
   using std::uniform_int_distribution<Int>::result_type;
   template<typename _URG> result_type operator()(_URG& __urng) const{
      return __urng()%(this->b() - this->a()) + this->a(); // never do this ;) for serious stuff, it is wrong in general for very subtle reasons
   }
// template<typename _URG> result_type operator()(_URG& __urng) = delete;
};
```

This stateless implementation is very "efficient" but not 100% correct for arbitrary values of `a` and `b` (limits of the distribution).
As you might see, for other distributions (including continuous distributions) this path is very difficult, tricky and error prone, so I don't recommend it.

---

This is mostly personal opinion: **Can the situations be improved?**

Yes, but only slightly.

The distributions could have two versions of `operator()`, one no-`const` (i.e. `&`), which is optimal (current one) and one that is `const` that what it can to not modify the state. However it is not clear whether they will be have to deterministically consistent (i.e. give same answers).
(Even fallback to copy will not give the same results as a full fledged mutable distribution.). However, I don't think this is a viable path (agreeing with the other answer); either you use an immutable version or an immutable version but not both at the same time.

What I think can be done is to have a mutable version but a specific overload for r-value references (`operator() &&`). 
This way the mechanism of the mutable version can be used but the now "useless" step of updating (e.g. resetting) the state can be omitted because the particular instance will not be used ever again. This way one can save some operations in some cases.

This way the `immutable` adaptor described above can be written in this way and exploit the semantics:

```
template<class Distribution>
struct immutable : Distribution{
   using Distribution::Distribution;
   using Distribution::result_type;
   template<typename _URG> result_type operator()(_URG& __urng) const{
      auto dist_copy = static_cast<Distribution>(*this);
      return std::move(dist_copy)(__urng);
// or return (Distribution(*this))(__urng);
   }
};
```