# c++ : template class vs two classes : efficiency

Tags: c++, performance, templates, c++11

I tried two things :

```
class RandDouble{
    public:
        RandDouble(double const& min_inclusive, double const& max_exclusive):
              mt_(std::random_device()),
              dist_(min_inclusive,max_exclusive)
         {}
        ~RandDouble(){}
        double get(){ return dist_(mt_); }

    private:
        std::mt19937_64 mt_;
        std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist_;
};

class RandUnsignedInt{
    public:
        RandUnsignedInt(unsigned int const& min_inclusive, unsigned int const& max_inclusive):
              mt_(std::random_device()),
              dist_(min_inclusive,max_exclusive)
         {}
       ~RandUnsignedInt(){}
        unsigned int get(){ return dist_(mt_); }

    private:
        std::mt19937_64 mt_;
        std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> dist_;
};
```

And

```
template<typename Type>
class Rand{
    public:
        Rand(Type const& min_inclusive, Type const& max_exclusive);/
        ~Rand();
        Type get();

    private:
        std::mt19937_64 mt_;
        std::uniform_real_distribution<double>* dist_double_;
        std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int>* dist_u_int_;
};
template<typename Type>
Rand<Type>::~Rand(){
    if(dist_double_){ delete dist_double_; }
    if(dist_u_int_){ delete dist_u_int_; }
}
```

with the `.cpp` file :

```
template<>
Rand<double>::Rand(double const& min_inclusive, double const& max_exclusive):
    mt_(std::random_device()()),
    dist_double_(new std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(min_inclusive,max_exclusive)),
    dist_u_int_(NULL)
{}

template<>
Rand<unsigned int>::Rand(unsigned int const& min_inclusive, unsigned int const& max_exclusive):
    mt_(std::random_device()()),
    dist_double_(NULL),
    dist_u_int_(new std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int>(min_inclusive,max_exclusive))
{}

template<>
double Rand<double>::get(){ return (*dist_double_)(mt_); }

template<>
unsigned int Rand<unsigned int>::get(){ return (*dist_u_int_)(mt_); }
```

From a practical point of view, the template solution is more flexible with other template classes because I could do things like :

```
template<typename Type>
classs C{
    /*some code*/
    private:
        Rand<Type> r;
};
```

So I like the template solution. But When I check the time it needs to call the `Rand<double/unsigned int>::get()` method I realized that it takes more than twice as much time than having a call from `RandDouble::get()` or `RandUnisignedint::get()`.

It there a way to keep the flexibility of the template method with a calling method that is as efficient as the one with two different classes.

Comment: As mentioned below the problem is with the pointer indirection. C++ Templates are actually created at pre-processor time and effectively make 2/3/4 classes for you under the hood. Therefore templates are not slower then hand tooled classes (depending on implementation) 

One thing I am very curious about is I can't see where you actually use mt_ within the class that needs higher precision then the type you are using.

Would it not be suitable to swap the line
" std::mt19937_64 mt_;"
for 
"T mt__;"

Comment: @chrispepper1989 I use mt_ in the get method... it is needed by either `std::uniform_real_distribution<double>` or `std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is probably the indirection you get by using pointers to the distribution classes. Try to use the classes directly without pointers, or maybe better do something like

```
typename std::conditional<std::is_integral<Type>::value
                        , std::uniform_int_distribution<Type>
                        , std::uniform_real_distribution<Type> >::type _dist;
```

in order to pick the distribution type you need. (This is just to give you a hint, the type-check could surely be improved).

---

**Explanation:** The code above works as follows: `std::conditional<(1),(2),(3)>` is just as a static if-statement for types. If the check in the first field `(1)` evaluates to true, it takes the type in the second field `(2)`, otherwise it picks the type in the third field `(3)`.

In case the template parameter `Type` is an integer type, `std::is_integral<Type>::value` will evaluate to `true`. Thus, the type of your distribution will be `std::uniform_int_distribution<Type>` which is usually desired.

In case `Type` it is not an integral type (but rather a floating-point type, which however isn't checked here), instead `std::uniform_real_distribution<Type>` is used for the type of the distribution.

Example ([tested here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8030ee2dba1affb6)):

```
#include<random>
#include<iostream>

template<typename Type>
struct UniformDistribution
{
    std::mt19937_64 mt_;
    typename std::conditional<std::is_integral<Type>::value
                            , std::uniform_int_distribution<Type>
                            , std::uniform_real_distribution<Type> >::type dist_;    
    Type get()
    {
        return dist_(mt_);
    }
};

int main()
{
     //produces uniformly distributed integer number in [0, numeric_limist<int>::max()]
     std::cout<<UniformDistribution<int>().get()<<std::endl;

     //produces uniformly distributed double number in [0,1]
     std::cout<<UniformDistribution<double>().get()<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: First time I see `std::conditional`... what is this ? And if I don't use pointer, Rand will create the two distributions, right ?

Comment: No, that's what the std::conditional is for. The type of _dist will be the one or the other depending on the the content of Type.

Comment: okay, I think I understand... the `std::conditional` creates a typename of different type depending of my template class... should I write this inside or outside my class ?

Comment: @PinkFloyd: I've added some explanation, hope it becomes clear.

Comment: it compiles... And it takes amlost the same time at the version with the two classes I had before ! I will do further test before accepting your answer.

Comment: @Pink Floyd: made another update to correct the code and add a minor modification (the `mutable`). Then it really should have the same speed as your classes before. In fact, this is the idea of templates: the compiler exactly generates the classes you had before, but with largely decreased coding effort.

Comment: Great ! Thank you for your help ! I run few tests and indeed the speed difference exists but is around 5% so that's okay : to genereate 2e10 random number it needs 102sec for my first method with two classes, 107sec for your method, and 108sec for Alexander's. I did 5 independents runs and I always get this kind of time

Comment: Is there any reason to make `get()` `const` and the members `mutable`? A common convention (observed by the standard library) is that concurrent calls to `const` member functions won't introduce data races - which this code obviously doesn't follow.

Comment: @T.C.: I asked myself the same after I've read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008271/why-are-c11-random-distributions-mutable). So no, there is no strict reason, it is just for convenience (I like passing by const-ref, and I like the mathematical view in which a distribution is just a const function). But it's probably safer not to use it.

Comment: @T.C.: when in doubt, don't do it. I've remove the `mutable`. Thnx for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<random>

template< class T >
struct TDist{};

template<> struct TDist<double> { std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist_; };
template<> struct TDist<unsigned int> { std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> dist_; };


template<typename Type>
class Rand : private TDist<Type> {
public:
    Rand(Type min_inclusive, Type max_exclusive) :
        mt_(std::random_device()),
        dist_(min_inclusive,max_exclusive)
    {}

    Type get(){ return dist_(mt_); }

private:
    std::mt19937_64 mt_;
};
```

Comment: @PinkFloyd: It will be as efficient as the approach in my answer. In fact, it is just another way to obtain the same behaviour, which is probably easier to understand and more flexible when an extension is required (such as adding further type-specific member functions). +1.

Comment: @Alexander Drichel: still, it would be better not to specify the types exactly (as `double` and `unsigned int`), but rather separate by integral and floating-point types. Otherwise `Rand<int>(0,1)` will fail to compile.

Comment: This code won't compile. `dist_` isn't a member of `Rand` and so cannot be initialized in the member initializer list of that class. Further, since `TDist` is a dependent base class, the call in `get()` needs to be prefixed with `this->` to make `dist_` a dependent name as otherwise name lookup won't find the base class member.